# Write a boolean function in template that determines if the logged user is either the node author or admin

Tags: 7, users

How do I write a function to determine if the user is either the node author or admin?

```
if ( logged user is author || admin ) {
  // …
}
```

It is for the node template.

Comment: Which template file do you want to alter?

Comment: Based on the title, this question could be one of three things. "How does boolean logic work (in PHP)?", "How do I determine if the user is also the author?", "How do I determine if the user is an admin?". Reading the question removes the first option. Downvoted for two questions in one, and a title that doesn't reflect the question well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this to template.php file of your theme:

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $user;

  if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles) || $variables['node']->uid == $user->uid) {
    $variables['is_admin_or_author'] = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    $variables['is_admin_or_author'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

then in your node.tpl.php or node--your-content-type.tpl.php you'll have a variable $is_admin_or_author with either TRUE or FALSE value.

Comment: This is a good answer, assuming that the question was about the node template.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking if the user is the author or admin, it is recommended to check for permissions to perform a certain action. That will make your system more flexible and you're fully taking advantage of the permission system already built into Drupal.

For instance, if you want to show/hide something depending on the permission to edit the current node, you can use this (assuming you're working with node.tpl.php):

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (node_access('update', $variables['node'])) {
    $variables['permission_to_edit'] = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    $variables['permission_to_edit'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Now you can use the following in your node.tpl.php:

```
if ($permission_to_edit) {
  print "You may edit this node!";
}
```

Comment: thanks marc, its useful idea, but its for flag module, to show something even when they aren't allowed to bookmark, so this won't work

Comment: Of course this is just an example, there may be other permissions you can check with [user_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) that are more appropriate for your situation. Flag module itself also has functions to check certain permissions (see http://api.lullabot.com/file/contrib/flag/flag.module/7). Anyway, the most important message is this: I would always prefer checking permissions over checking user IDs or roles.

Comment: This is the Drupal way: You never check if the user has a specific role, but if the user has a specific permission. The reason is maintainability of the code: Suppose you add more roles, you don't need to rewrite all the `if`-statements because the code would always be `if (user_access('get hamburgers')) { }`.

Comment: well i checked off the ability to flag if their are either author/admin/anonymous, which create flag link will return null. i thought it would be easier this way, to check if they are logged/admin/author than show something else

Answer (score 1):

```
global $user;

if ($node->uid == $user->uid || $user->uid == 1) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

You can also check for user roles by adding `in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))` to the if statement if you had a seperate role (webmaster for example).